# What does this ∩ symbol mean in terms of geometry

Tags: geometry

I don't know what this symbol mean in terms of high school geometry. I've search in google for it but I was unable to find anything about it(in terms of geometry). I'm reading a proof in which is said that

```
(AB || CD) ∩ CK BKC = KCD = α1
```

Here is drawing:

[image: Here is drawing:]

Comment: Can you give more context on how you saw it used?

Comment: I edited my question, I hope that this helps

Comment: So what means (AB || CD) ∩ CK  ?

Comment: Why did you remove the image?  The image made it clearer.  Now everyone is going to just assume it's standard set notation.

Comment: I rolled back the last edit to make the drawing visible again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the symbol for intersection of two sets. If used between geometrical objects (points, lines, etc.) then it means their intersection (because we can think about them as sets of points).

For example, if we have:

```
A ------------- B ------------- C ------------- D
```

then the intersection of the lines $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BD}$ would be the line $\overline{BC}$. A way to write this in symbols would be:

$$
\overline{AC} \cap \overline{BD} = \overline{BC}
$$

Comment: So what does in mean in the context above?  (AB || CD) isn't a geometric construct; it's a statement-- AB is parallel to CD.  How can that be intersected with a line?

Comment: @fleablood: I agree -- your answer seems like a good guess (more helpful than mine in this context), and I upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I *think* it means "intersects" as in: AB is parallel to CD and both of those lines intersect CK.

I think the next part, the "BKC = KCD = $\alpha 1$" is a separate statement about angle measures.